# Unable to get WinJS.xhr to properly retrieve XML file

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Here is what I have:

```
function HelloFeed(WPFeedUrl) {
    var title, articles;
    WinJS.xhr({ url: WPFeedUrl }).then(function (rss) {
        title = rss.responseXML.querySelector("title").textContent;
        var items = rss.responseXML.querySelectorAll("item");

        for (var n = 0; n < items.length; n++) {
            var article = {};
            article.title = items[n].querySelector("title").textContent;
            var thumbs = items[n].querySelectorAll("content");
            article.content = items[n].querySelector("encoded").textContent;
            if (thumbs.length > 1) {
                article.thumbnail = thumbs[thumbs.length - 1].attributes.getNamedItem("url").textContent;
            }
            else {
                var firstindex = article.content.indexOf("<img");
                if (firstindex !== -1) {
                    var secondindex = article.content.indexOf("src=", firstindex) + 5;
                    var thirdindex = article.content.indexOf("\"", secondindex);
                    article.thumbnail = article.content.slice(secondindex, thirdindex);
                }
            }
            BasketballItems.push({ group: BasketballGroups[0], title: "hello", content: "h", backgroundImage: lightGray });
        }
    });
}
```

If I place `BasketballItems.push({ group: BasketballGroups[0], title: "hello", content: "h", backgroundImage: lightGray });` outside the `WinJS.xhr` block of code, it successfully adds an element to the array `BasketballItems`, however if I put it inside that big block of code, it doesn't function. I am calling the function like this: `HelloFeed("http://allball.blogs.nba.com/feed/");`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be the classic mistake of trying to use data that is processed after an asynchronous operation before the asynchronous operation has finished and run the callback. Whatever code needs `BasketballItems` should be called as part of that code block. For example:

```
BasketballItems.push({ group: BasketballGroups[0], title: "hello", content: "h", backgroundImage: lightGray });
myOtherCode(BasketballItems);
```

and then put the code that needs to know about those items in that function. It's just another callback.

```
function myOtherCode(items) {
  console.log(items); // <--- code in here knows about the push, since it occurs in the callback chain after the asynchronous operation (WinJS.xhr)
}
```

Depending on the scope, you may not need to pass in `BasketballItems` as I did there. It looks like you can just access it implicitly, but I don't recommend having such non-encapsulated variables.

To clarify my meaning, you might also be able to just do this in the callback:

```
function myOtherCode() {
  console.log(BasketballItems);
}
```

Of course, you could also not use a function and just dump all of your code right there instead, but it's better to try to break your code up more.

Comment: I am a little confused by your solution and answer, however, if it makes it any clearer, here is the entire data.js file that I have: http://pastebin.com/cmZMG1A2